# Can't receive c2d messages from Azure Function App(Node)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am building an IoT system using Azure IoT Hub, 2 ESP32 devices(one is to send sensor values and another is to receive c2d message and activate an actuator) and an Azure Function to store the values to a database.

To send c2d messages from an Azure function app, I used the following code.(This Azure Function is triggered when IoT Hub gets a mqtt message from my ESP32 device.)
But I couldn't receive them on my mosquitto_subscribe script running on my laptop.

code in the function app

```js
import { AzureFunction, Context } from "@azure/functions"
const Client = require('azure-iothub').Client;
const Message = require('azure-iot-common').Message;
const connectionString = 'my connection string';
const targetDevice = 'my device id';
const serviceClient = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

const IoTHubTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, message: {type:string;isPressed:boolean;}): Promise<void> {
    context.log(`Eventhub trigger function called for message : ${JSON.stringify(message)}`);
    context.log(message)
    context.log(message.isPressed)
    if(message.isPressed){
        try {
            await serviceClient.open()
            context.log('Service client connected');
            //   serviceClient.getFeedbackReceiver(receiveFeedback);
            const csdMessage = new Message('This is a C2D message');
            csdMessage.ack = 'full';
            csdMessage.messageId = "My Message ID";
            context.log('Sending message: ' + csdMessage.getData());
            await serviceClient.send(targetDevice, csdMessage);
        }catch(err){
            context.log('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
        }
        
    }
    context.done();
};

export default IoTHubTrigger;
```

mosquitto code

```sh
mosquitto_sub -d -q 1 \
  -V mqttv311 \
  -p 8883 \
  -h my-iot-hub-name.azure-devices.net \
  -i esp32\
  -u "my-iot-hub-name.azure-devices.net/my-decice-name/api-version=2016-11-14" \
  -P "$SAS" \
  -t "devices/my-device-name/messages/devicebound/#"
```

According to the execution log, the connection between IoT Hub and the Function was successfully established and the message was sent.
[execution log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThqnA.png)

What confuses me is that the mosquitto script can receive c2d messages when I run the local node script which is almost the same as the one in Function App.
I wrote the following script referring to this document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-c2d#send-a-cloud-to-device-message

```js
'use strict';

var Client = require('azure-iothub').Client;
var Message = require('azure-iot-common').Message;

var connectionString = 'my connection string';
var targetDevice = 'my device id';

var serviceClient = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

(async()=>{
    try {
        await serviceClient.open()
        console.log('Service client connected');
        //   serviceClient.getFeedbackReceiver(receiveFeedback);
        const csdMessage = new Message('This is a C2D message');
        csdMessage.ack = 'full';
        csdMessage.messageId = "My Message ID";
        console.log('Sending message: ' + csdMessage.getData());
        await serviceClient.send(targetDevice, csdMessage);
    }catch(err){
        console.log('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
    }
})();
```

Why can't c2d messages reach mosquitto_sub only when they are from function app even though the function to send a message is successfully executed ?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you mean C2D (cloud-to-device), not D2C (device-to-cloud), right? If so, I recommend you update your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Yes that’s exactly what i meant. i’ll fix it. You saved me. Thanks,again

Comment: You can refer to [Use the Eclipse Mosquitto library to send messages to the MQTT Broker implemented in the IoT hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5002324#example-in-c-using-mqtt-without-an-azure-iot-sdk) and [Clients not receiving subscribed messages at volume](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/16)

Comment: Thanks. The reference is really useful.

Comment: But this time it had nothing to do with how to use library. It was my fault. I registered only one device on IoTHub. I should have registered 2 devices. One is for sending D2C message and another is for receiving  C2D. Once I set 2 devices on IoTHub, everything worked fine.